# Bootstrap ScrollSpy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello guys I'm using bootstrap scroll spy. when I click on the link it takes me to that specific portion but the problem that I am facing   is that when I'm scrolling up or down the options is not becoming active. I don't know why am I facing this problem. Please help. Here is my code. I

```
<div id="buyer_guide" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">
  <div  class="col-lg-6 ">
    <div id="content ">
      <section id="section-1">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod </p>
          <hr />
          <a href="#top">&uarr; Back to top</a> <a href="#" rel="next">&darr; Next section</a> </div>
      </section>
      <section id="section-2">
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod </p>
          <hr />
          <a href="#top">&uarr; Back to top</a> <a href="#" rel="next">&darr; Next section</a> </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <nav id="myScrollspy" >
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved your problem. Here is the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">

<div id="buyer_guide">
  <div class="row">
    <div  class="col-lg-6 ">
      <div id="content ">
        <section id="section-1">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>Section 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod </p>
            <hr />
            <a href="#top">&uarr; Back to top</a> <a href="#" rel="next">&darr; Next section</a> </div>
        </section>
        <section id="section-2">
          <div class="content">
            <h2>Section 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod </p>
            <hr />
            <a href="#top">&uarr; Back to top</a> <a href="#" rel="next">&darr; Next section</a> </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-3">
      <nav id="myScrollspy">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="active"><a href="#section-1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section-2">Section 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You should add **.nav** class to your ul element inside the nav, **.active** class to one of the list items as default, set data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20" attributes to the **body** tag instead of **#buyer_guide** div, and could you please be sure the add all the JS and CSS files below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thoise attributes are set to buyers div.

Comment: did you mean that I have to set them to body not to the buyer's_guide. and no this is not the problem. The problem is that when I try to scroll down to see all other section the section which is in focus it's option should be active or highlighted

Comment: @Gardezi I got your question.. You mean scrolled link should be activated. "active" class should be dynamically added to the li element by bootstrap.js. Could you please send jsfiddle link by putting your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Yes I meant that. I was inspecting the code and I found out that it was not applying the active class

Comment: I have included the bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css files. I can't figure out why am I facing this problem

Comment: do you have any idea why am I facing this problem.

Comment: I have solved it, could you please check my edited solution.

Comment: I still have one question should I apply this  `data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20" ` to body or buyers guide ?

Comment: just give me 10 minutes. I will be near my laptop in 10 minutes then I can tell you if it's working or not

Comment: sorry for the late reply my internet was not working that was I was not able to reply to you earlier and it is still not working for me

Comment: Could you please try again with the edited? You can copy the code and past the editor here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy2&stacked=h and see it works. If it still doesn't work, could you please create one jsfiddle, put your codes inside, and write the link here.

Comment: I just checked it does not works when I give this `data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20"` to a div. It is only working if I give it o body

Comment: Yep, I got the same conclusion just 5 minutes ago and that's why I changed my solution by setting them to body.

Comment: but the problem with mine is that even after I give it to body it doesn't works. That what I can't understand why doesn't it works for me. My conclusion is maybe it is expecting a div which have all of this content right after the body but well who knows. I just opened a issue. Let's see what will they have to say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106926/discussion-between-kaan-burak-sener-and-gardezi).